# How to prevent WCF-SQL adapter to roll back transaction if no data is returned

Tags: biztalk

I am using typedpolling with stored procedures using ambient transaction. PollingAvailable statement gives "all" rows count. Polling statement gives only a subset of valid rows, and sometimes none.

In the polling procedure I need to be able to exclude some results based on some business logic. Sometimes there are no rows returned from the procedure, which leads to the WCF-SQL adapter doing rollback on the transaction. And, polling process gets looped  until at least one valid row is returned.

I don't like to disable ambient transaction because of the "valid" results I'd like to return, if something happens later in the process.

Stored procedure transaction directives (used as my "standard"):

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

Any ideas of a workaround?
Committing an inner transaction I guess will be rolled back anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the 'correct' solution is to craft the PollingDataAvailableStatement to return the proper value 0 or >0 depending on the expected output of the polling statement.

I situations where it's mattered, because it doesn't always matter :), I've added a flag to the SP to indicate it's called from PollingDataAvailableStatement so the SP can so some of it's logic to determine if data is available and return that signal.

Of course, you can use a separate SP, but I'd prefer to keep the logic in one place for maintenance reasons.

Comment: The solution I ended up with! Thanks for the tip to have only one procedure, makes sense now that the PollingAvailable-procedure's logics got more complex.